# Difference between “with”, “at” and “for” with a business title and a company name

Tags: differences, prepositions, at-with

The prepositions “with”, “at” and “for” are also used to associate a business title with a company's name. It seems that they are interchangeable, with no (significant) difference in meaning. The following examples taken from The New York Times website seem to confirm that:

> Until now, said Justin Nielson, a **senior analyst for** the media
>   research firm SNL Kagan, “there really hasn't been any direct
>   competitor . . .
>
> “The consumer is still deleveraging,” said Jason Goldberg, a **senior
>   analyst with** Barclays. “It's not a lack of supply; it's a lack of
>   demand.”
>
> “There’s the party of fear and the party of despair,” Nikos Xydakis, a
>   political analyst and an **editor at** Kathimerini daily, said.

Are they really the same as for meaning? If it isn't so, what is the difference between them?

Comment: Also "of" for unique (high-powered) business titles, such as "CEO of Motorola" ( http://bbc.co.uk/news/technology-23544430 ) and "chairman of The New York Times Company" ( http://nytimes.com/2013/08/08/business/media/times-co-chairman-declares-paper-not-for-sale.html ).

Comment: 'At' distances and 'for' hints of forced labour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The three prepositions imply three different things:

***For*** emphasizes the employer-employee relationship. If I work *for* a company, they issue my paycheck, and they can fire me for poor performance.

***At*** emphasizes the locale where I work. If I work *at* a company, I usually park in their parking lot, and work in their building each workday.

***With*** emphasizes that I'm part of a team.  If I work *with* a company, then that company's workers are my co-workers.

The words are essentially interchangeable in many contexts, because many of us do all three at the three time.  If I was employed at Nike, for example, I could say that I work *for* Nike (they issue my paycheck), *at* Nike (I work in their building), and *with* Nike (I work with their employees).  Quite often, saying one implies the other two.

One of the three prepositions may become less appropriate if one of those three conditions isn't true.  If Nike hires me as an independent consultant or specialist, and they allow to me work from home, I might be less prone to use *at*.  If I serve on an advisory board in a part-time, volunteer capacity, I might be more inclined to use *with*, and less inclined to use *for*.

Answer (score 3):

They are used interchangeably. If you are an independent consultant, though, *with* sounds better than *at* or *for*, since your relationship with the company is not as an employee but as a separate business.

Answer (score 1):

I have been taught that the right grammatical expression is **work for** company X. But I just Googled and **work for** and **work at** are the [trends](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work%20at%2Cwork%20with%2Cwork%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwork%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20for%3B%2Cc0) and even sites like [glassdoor](http://www.glassdoor.com) use work at. So I guess it is up to your taste. I would use **work with** when talking about group of people.

**E.g**:

> You will work with programmers ,experts in their field, and top notch technologies.