# Should I say I work "for" or "with" my supervisor?

Tags: word-choice, differences, verbs

I have heard people saying both "I work for him" and "I work with him" when they are talking about their supervisors. But, since these people were not native English speakers, I could not figure out which one was the correct one.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: The accepted answer [at another question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71368/difference-between-with-at-and-for-with-a-business-title-and-a-company-na) may answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either could be correct, but they definitely have different meanings. I work **for** a supervisor, but I work **with** a colleague. If you and your boss actually collaborate, or if there's a feeling of being on a team together, then you work *with* him; but if she just tells you what to do, and you do it -- if it's entirely one-directional -- then you work *for* her.

You would also specifically use *for* to make the supervisory relationship clear, even in a cooperative situation.