# What is the proper preposition for "(job title) in / at / of (company name)"?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

I am writing a cover letter for my job application, and I am not sure which preposition is proper to use at a sentence as below.
"Hereby, I am applying for the position of AAA (position title) **in** BBB (company name)."

I am not sure if "in" is the correct one or not. How about "at" or "of", instead of using "in".

- I am applying for the position of AAA (job title) **in** BBB (company name).
- I am applying for the position of AAA (job title) **at** BBB (company name).
- I am applying for the position of AAA (job title) **of** BBB (company name).

And if you can tell me why, I would appreciate.
(Using proper preposition is the most difficult part for/to(?) me.)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71368/difference-between-with-at-and-for-with-a-business-title-and-a-company-na?rq=1

Comment: @JeffSahol, Thank you for the link. Then can I use "for" or "with" in this sentence as well?

Comment: That is correct, you can use "for" also. For what it's worth, the one distinction that I can see is that "of" would mainly apply to one-of-a-kind jobs, CEO for example. You would tend to say that X is an accountant *at* BBB, and Y is the CFO *of* BBB. That is not a hard "rule", though.

Comment: @JeffSahol, that's a very helpful comment. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @JeffSahol, sorry, but let me clarify it. So what you are saying is that putting "for", "of" or "with" would be better than using "in" or "at" in the sentence above.

Comment: I would definitely not use "in"...never heard it used in this context. Never applied for a CEO job so I'd not use "of", either.

"At" is what I'd normally use. "For" or "with" is what I might use after having the job: "I am an accountant with BBB; I do accounting for BBB." (I can't explain the reasoning or rules behind this, just what sounds right to my ear.)

Comment: "In" would be appropriate if the following word is a department or division.  For example, I am applying for Chief Accountant in the Logistics Department at the University of Homeville.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the title.

> I would like to be the President *of* the United States

Because there is only one.

> I would like to be a Manager *at* Burger King

Because there are many and that would be where you work.

> I would like to be a Senior Airman *in* the Air Force.

Because you would be a member.